# Return name of the row with its maximum value from certain column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am writing a function that has arguments of utensil but actually returns the name of the brand that sells in maximum cost using data frame below:

```
   utensil cost brand
1  pen     1    a
2  pencil  2    b
3  pen     5    c
4  pen     6    d
5  pencil  2    e
```

Comment: show what you have written so far

Comment: `with(subset(mydf, mydf$utensil == "pen"), brand[which.max(cost)])`

Comment: Just calculate everything: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(utensil) %>% summarise(brand = brand[which.max(cost)])`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
highestCostBrand <- function(strUtensil)
{
  highestCostIndex <- max(as.double(df[which(df$utensil==strUtensil),]$cost))
  return(df[highestCostIndex,3])
}
```

Comment: Please provide some amount of explanation for why your approach works.

Answer (score 0):

This function resolves your problem

```
dados = data.frame(utensil = c('pen', 'pencil', 'pen', 'pen', 'pencil'),
                   cost = c(1,2,5,6,2),
                   brand = c('a','b','c','d','e'))


verify = function(utensil, dados){

  selected = dados[dados$utensil == utensil,]

  result <- as.character(selected[which.max(dados[dados$utensil == utensil, 'brand']),'brand'])

  return(result)
}
```